# Remove git commits and navigate to master

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-push

I am trying to delete commits that haven't been pushed yet. The only one in this list I want to commit is the one with the message MT, then I want to navigate to master if I'm not there already. I've tried `git reset HEAD~` and `git reset --hard` which didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`interactive rebase` ([reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)) is probably what you want.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Then, in the file that opens, delete all lines except the commits you want to keep, save and close.

Note, that dropping commits like this cannot be undone.